# Mediaelement.js displays grey bars on some browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mp4, mediaelement.js

I have video embedded on a site with mediaelement.js.  The video shows properly an all browsers except PC Firefox and PC Chrome, where the video displays strange grey bars on the right and bottom of the videos.  I'm sure this is some kind of encoding issue, but not sure how to resolve it.

My code looks like this

```
<style>
.video embed,.video object, .video iframe, video { width: 100%; height: auto; }
</style>

<video width="960" height="540" style=" cursor:pointer;width: 100%; height: 100%; max-width:960px; max-height:540px; margin: 0 0 0 0; z-index:0;" id="player1" preload="true">
<source type="video/mp4" src="video.mp4" />
</video>
<script src="mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaelementplayer.min.css" />

<script>
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player1', {features:['playpause','backlight','progress','current','duration','volume'],
startLanguage:'en',alwaysShowControls: false,hideControls: true, defaultVideoWidth: 960,defaultVideoHeight: 540
    });

    player.hideControls();
    player.play();
    player.pause();
</script>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, and I couldn't find any solution. So I made quick fix: I made video area bigger so grey bars are now out of my visible area (I've also set overflow: hidden to parent).

Comment: Unfortunately that wont work for my case.  Is it perhaps an issue with encoding?  These videos look fine on Mac.

Comment: Yeah - Mac works well as well as Flash fallback for old browsers.

Comment: Any way to combat that?  Or is choosing flash the only option since the videos seem to be encoded incorrectly or interpreted incorrectly?

Comment: I don't have many exp with videos encodings and encoding process itself. But the problem is with <video> tag implemented in chrome. I hope they will resolve this issue. I thought that it might be connected with wrong mime type, but it's not - I checked it in my case.